# Names of fields in forms and in database - must they be identical?

Tags: php, html, forms, security

I have a web form. Should I use the same names for the fields in the form and in the database, so I can benefit from it and achieve shorten code as this (PHP):

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $value){
    if( is_allowed_field( $key ) ) $fields_to_insert[ $key ] = sanitize_string( $value );  
    ....
} //
```

Or that identical structure could expose the database structure to a bad intention individual? Should I use different names, for example, with a prefix ? So, which is the better approach?

The second aproach would be, for example, to name input name="passw" and in the database table, the field called password, for example.

Comment: They don't have to be equal, no. In fact many use conventions that give them camelCased names in code and snake_case names in the database.

Comment: But that convention will not add security, as it is fixed and previsible.

Comment: No naming will do nothing for security.

Comment: Using identical names doesn't add security either, it just makes the developer more lazy as he uses then a loop like you above and just 'sanitize' everything using the same ruleset and not use the correct ruleset for the correct use.

Comment: I think over all the question is opinion-based, but a fact to consider is that this approach will tightly couple your presentation layer to your data layer. To many people, this would be undesirable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not should.. 
you can do this implementation but you have to be careful about what data 
the user is sending. 
because at client side ( forms and html ) are easy to be changed.
Also the user can add any input he want.
so first of all you have to be careful about data you are receiving from user.
another thing your database structure will be available for everyone, and this is not good sometimes.
also it is more clean to show what variables you are receiving in your code.
not just force the developer to put the accepted fields in allowed_fields...
because at this point he may forget something. or add a secret field...

**I prefer to be more clear even if you typed an extra 10 lines of code.**